# Error in referencing EventHub assembly in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

We are receiving the following error whilst trying to post a message from Azure HTTP trigger function to Event Hub. I have not included the complete code because I am getting the error when I include the namespace itself.

```
>  2018-03-05T12:49:47.912 [Info] Function started
> (Id=da357e2a-3604-4dd1-b199-646ffcc91469)
>     2018-03-05T12:49:47.912 [Error] Function compilation error
>     2018-03-05T12:49:47.912 [Error] run.csx(2,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EventHubs' does not exist in the namespace
> 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>     2018-03-05T12:49:47.928 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.EventsHandler. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script:
> Script compilation failed.
>     2018-03-05T12:49:47.944 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=da357e2a-3604-4dd1-b199-646ffcc91469, Duration=29ms)
```

This is my function code

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{// variable declarations
    private static EventHubClient eventHubClient;
    private const string EhConnectionString = "{Event Hubs connection string}";
    private const string EhEntityPath = "{Event Hub path/name}";

   }
```

My project.json

```
{"frameworks":
    {"net461":
        {"dependencies":
            {"Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs":"1.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What might be the reason for this error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions (current version v1) is using `Microsoft.ServiceBus` client for Event Hubs. You don't need to reference any extra NuGet packages for that from `project.json`, just do

```cs
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
```

on top of your Function script.

Furthermore, I would advise against using `EventHubClient` manually. You should try using [Output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output) instead.

Comment: It worked . The reason why im trying manually is  i need to convert an xml to JSON before pushing it to Event hub . Second i need to give a response to the client which is invoking my function through an HTTP trigger. Can i mention two output bindings variables in my functions.json

Comment: You can convert to JSON and then push it to output binding. You can have two (or more) output bindings: event hub one will use `IAsyncCollector`.